# What happens on a Release Upgrade when a package is not supported in the Ubuntu repositories anymore?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, repository, do-release-upgrade

I have asked [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693831/what-happens-when-a-program-gets-removed-from-the-software-center) a couple of years ago, but it wasn't related to a system upgrade and more focused on potentially malicious software or licensing issues.

Since I am considering regularly upgrading to minor, non-LTS Releases, I was wondering what happens to installed programs that have no supported package in the Release repository anymore with a `do-release-upgrade` or `apt dist-upgrade`.

As an example, [Amarok](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amarok) currently has no package in any repository after 18.04, since Qt4-based software had been removed lately. What would have happened to my Amarok installation, if I had installed it on 18.04 LTS and upgraded to 18.10?

Would it have been removed from my system on upgrade? Or would it stay on the last package version until a new package was available?

My previous question suggests that it would likely stay in the last supported version on my system, but I believe to have read that some software was removed on a system upgrade.

Comment: Unsupported packages will be removed by `do-release-upgrade`. `dist-upgrade` is unrelated to upgrading from one release to another`.

Comment: Hello Pilot6, okay, that's interesting. I was wondering where the difference might be, because https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html still lists `dist-upgrade` as a way to upgrade releases.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

Comment: I don't really understand how that question relates to release upgrades. So `dist-upgrade` will remove packages if the dependencies change, but the `sources.list` file still needs to be manually updated, whereas with `do-release-upgrade` that's not the case? How else would there be any changes besides the ones in the release repository?

Comment: `dist-upgrade` doesn't upgrade to a new release, that's you need to understand. It is deprecated now and replaced by `full-upgrade` probably not to confuse people ;-)

Comment: If you *specified* Amarok to be installed (apt-mark:auto), then it will be retained. If Amarok was merely dragged in as dependency (apt-mark:manual), then it will be removed.

Comment: Would `apt install amarok` constitute as being `apt-mark:auto`? Meaning that even when I `do-release-upgrade` it won't be removed although the package is no longer available?